# Emulators and Roms

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I just flagged a pair of topics regarding emulation today and wanted to stop by to check if I went about that correctly.  One topic, [Disabling Music on GBA Final Fantasy Tactics Advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303500/disabling-music-on-gba-final-fantasy-tactics-advance), is requesting help with an emulated copy of FFTA, and is the flag I'm most confident about.  I took a shot at editing out the reference to ROMs, but it seems pretty integral to the point of the question, so I went with a flag instead.

The other, [How to set BIOS file in go PSX emulator free?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303491/how-to-set-bios-file-in-go-psx-emulator-free) is the one I'm more conflicted on.  I know that legally speaking, emulators are okay as long as all the software you use is dumped from your own personal library, but I was under the impression we just don't allow emulation discussion at all as it would fall under software, not gaming.  If I'm wrong that's fine, I just want to clear it up.

I'm aware of the question on our [official stance](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102), but that has no accepted answer, and the top two voted ones are very close and of almost opposite opinions.  If there is a way I can bump that topic without leaving a useless answer on it, I'd be glad to know.  Creating my own question seemed like the best way to get attention on the subject again.

Answer (score 3):

> One topic, Disabling Music on GBA Final Fantasy Tactics Advance, is requesting help with an emulated copy of FFTA, and is the flag I'm most confident about. I took a shot at editing out the reference to ROMs, but it seems pretty integral to the point of the question, so I went with a flag instead.

The OP is asking how to disable the music but keep the sound, whether that is in the game or via an emulator.

As far as I am aware, we should be able to provide answers to such questions.  Perhaps you are assuming the ROM was obtained illegally?  We cannot tell that is the case, and we should assume the question is asked in good faith.

> The other, How to set BIOS file in go PSX emulator free? is the one I'm more conflicted on. I know that legally speaking, emulators are okay as long as all the software you use is dumped from your own personal library, but I was under the impression we just don't allow emulation discussion at all as it would fall under software, not gaming. If I'm wrong that's fine, I just want to clear it up.

We have a tag for such questions, and I feel that such questions fall within:

> Game-specific hardware and utilities

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Both questions seem to fit in with other questions asked within the [emulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) tag:

[Top emulation questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation?sort=votes&pageSize=50)