# Reopen, then close again with different motive?

Tags: discussion, closing, reopen

[How do I run a downloaded Pokemon Fire Red Save File?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307326/pokemon-fire-red-save-file-download-gba-chrome-emulator)

This question was initially closed as unclear. It has been edited, and it's probably about illegal emulation; even if it is not, it is a good example.

#### If a question changes reason to be closed, should it be reopened ?

Comment: It's not illegal to discuss an emulator's save files, nor is it off topic for us: [What's the official stance on console emulation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/whats-the-official-stance-on-console-emulation)

Comment: Yes, I know this. This question is only an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is closed for whatever reason, it's closed. Reopening it just to close it with another reason doesn't make sense.

You're either:

- Making extra work for a mod to reopen and then close it with whatever reason you think it actually needs or
- You need 5 people to vote to reopen and then 5 new people to vote to close. Which is a lot of overhead for something that ultimately doesn't really matter in any real sense.

Leave a comment to point it out, if you really feel the wrong close reason has been applied. But if you just want it to stay closed with a different label, reopening it isn't really helpful, and you can possibly reach a point where a question that should be closed remains open for longer than it should just because the reason was being changed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!