# Is asking about getting a game ROM to run on a type of architecture off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Specifically, I own Pokemon Puzzle League, but I'd like to try and run it on my MacOS for easier screen capture.  The problem is, on MacOS it doesn't run with Mupen64 emulator core.  I can't find any details regarding other, potential options for this.

I'd like to ask about this specific game, which is well documented as "not working" but I can't find anything referencing a viable solution.  Is this on-topic?

Note, I would not post a link to a ROM, I'd just mention that this specific game does not work with known N64 cores on MacOS, and if there is a solution.

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be fine.  See [What's the official stance on console emulation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/whats-the-official-stance-on-console-emulation) for a bit more details, but essentially emulation questions are generally accepted.

Also see the [emulation tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/emulation/info) wiki:

> This tag should be used concerning questions that involve the emulation of video games. Note that actually linking to ROM sites are not allowed as per the Arqade Meta post, [What's the official stance on console emulation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102/whats-the-official-stance-on-console-emulation) See the aforementioned meta post for more info.

You don't plan on posting a link to the ROM - good!

I would probably tag the question with [emulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) [pokemon-puzzle-league](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-puzzle-league) [macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)