# I have a potential recommendation question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-recommendations

I want to make sure this won't break the rules, so I'm asking here first.

I am on the final trophy of Pacman World Repac, which is to beat level 9 of Original Pacman. There 3 are patterns to follow, one for level 1, one for levels 2-4, and one for levels 5 and on to far past level 9. I can get through levels 1-4 without any trouble, as the patterns aren't terrible. But the pattern for level 5 and on is much more complex, and I am struggling to practice it. It's also annoying spending 5 minutes to get to level 5, just to fail the pattern and have to restart.

I want to avoid asking a recommendation question, but I still want to know how best to practice this pattern. I've tried emulating old Pacman world games for PS1/2, but the Original Pacman implementations in those games is a different ROM, and not the one from Repac (supposedly the *original* arcade cabinet is in Repac). How can I best proceed on Arqade, or is Reddit maybe a better place to ask?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question, as it is, is not an off-topic recommendation question. The question isn't a request for *subjective* recommendation advice, unlike the ones described in the Stack Overflow blog post, "[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)". While some might see it as an off-topic recommendation question, I would like to remind everyone of the community consensus in multiple prior Arqade Meta posts about the matter:

- ["These [types of] questions *describe a problem* and then *request a specific solution to that problem.*"](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5548/4797)
- ["**Judge questions by *the problem being posed*** instead of the presupposed answer."](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797)
- ["Closing the question because a [recommendation] request is present doesn't make sense."](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8168/4797)
- ["Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves [recommendation], so be it."](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11579/4797)

Comment: Cool, okay. I guess another question is, if I now know the answer to the above proposed question, is it bad faith to answer it too? The answer is to emulate the original midway cabinet with an emulator and a ROM, which I'm not sure is an acceptable answer due to *PiRaCy* or whatever..

Comment: @nightsurfer [Answering your own question is actually encouraged in Stack Exchange sites.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) On Arqade's Emulation policy, see: [What's the official stance on console emulation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/102/4797)

Comment: Thank you. I think I can safely proceed now :)